# Cannot find documented data

Tags: r, package

I'm creating a new package and documenting lookup tables stored in the data/ folder using an R script as per the instructions here http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html. I have two `.rda` tables, one for looking up the product based on a product code and another looking up the category based on the category code. (e.g. data/productlookup.rda)

Here's an except of my documented data which is stored in the R/ folder of the package.

```
#' ProductDecodes: Extract info from Product Codes
#'
#' This package contains functions for the extraction of information
#' from Product codes.
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name productDecoding
NULL

#' Product lookup
#'
#' @source internal
"productlookup"

#' Category lookup
#'
#' @source internal
"categorylookup"
```

However, when I come to `roxygenise` the package I get an error stating the `.rda` tables cannot be found.

```
Error in get(name, envir = env) : object 'productlookup' not found
```

The error doesn't occur when the tables are loaded into the global environment first. What I want to know is whether it is possible to `roxygenise` the package without having to load the `.rda` into the global environment first? I don't understand why `roxygenise` needs the lookup tables to be in the global environment in order to find them. Any help/explanation of why this error is occurring would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I usually do and I've just tested successfully with roxygen2 5.0.1:

```
#' Product lookup
#'
#' @format A data.frame with 200 rows and 2 variables:
#' \itemize{
#'   \item prod: product name
#'   \item val: product value in US$
#' }
#'
#' @source internal
#' @name productlookup
NULL
```

Of course, the resulting help page needs more information.

Comment: Great that works, the only shame is that some of the information in the `.Rd` file is lost such as: 
 `\format{An object of class \code{data.frame} with 37 rows and 2 columns.}`. But at least I won't have to load the tables each time I edit the package and roxegenise :) I'll accept if there is no better answers. I'd still like to know why it doesn't work with the method suggested in http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html.

Comment: I don't understand. Use `@format` to document the format. That's what I mean with my last sentence. I've assumed you omitted that for the minimal example.

Comment: With `@format` you have to write the format your self, where as the above `#' Product lookup
#'
#' @source internal
"productlookup"` Will document the format for you. Possibly the reason it needs to be loaded into the global environment! So may well explain the second part of my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, usually I want to give more information than can be inferred from the data.frame object automatically. I want to explain what the columns represent.